# R create NetCDF from .CSV

Tags: r, gis, netcdf

I am trying to create a NetCDF from a .csv file. I have read several tutorials here and other places and still have some doubts.

I have a table according to this:

```
lat,long,time,rh,temp
41,-109,6,1,1
40,-107,18,2,2
39,-105,6,3,3
41,-103,18,4,4
40,-109,6,5,2
39,-107,18,6,4
```

I create the NetCDF using the ncdf4 package in R.

```
xvals <- data$lon
yvals <- data$lat 
nx <- length(xvals)
ny <- length(yvals)
lon1 <- ncdim_def("longitude", "degrees_east", xvals)
lat2 <- ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees_north", yvals)
time <- data$time
mv <- -999 #missing value to use

var_temp <- ncvar_def("temperatura", "celsius", list(lon1, lat2, time), longname="Temp. da superfície", mv) 

var_rh <- ncvar_def("humidade", "%", list(lon1, lat2, time), longname = "humidade relativa", mv )

ncnew <- nc_create(filename, list(var_temp, var_rh))
ncvar_put(ncnew, var_temp, dadostemp, start=c(1,1,1), count=c(nx,ny,nt))
```

When I follow the procedure it states that the NC expects 3 times the number of data that I have.
I understand why, one matrix for each dimension, since I stated that the variables are according to the Longitude, Latitude and Time.

So, how would I import this kind of data, where I already have one Lon, Lat, Time and other variables for each data acquisition?

Could someone shed some light?

PS: The data used here is not my real data, just some example I was using for the tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is more than one problem in your code. Step by step:

**Create dimensions**

In a nc file dimensions don't work as key-values there just a vector of values defining what each position in a variable array means.
This means you should create your dimensions like this:

```
xvals <- unique(data$lon)
xvals <- xvals[order(xvals)]
yvals <- yvals[order(unique(data$lat))] 
lon1 <- ncdim_def("longitude", "degrees_east", xvals)
lat2 <- ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees_north", yvals)
time <- data$time
time_d <- ncdim_def("time","h",unique(time))
```

Where I work we use unlimited dimensions as mere indexes while a 1d-variable with same name as the dimension holds the values. I'm not sure how unlimited dimensions work in R. Since you don't ask for it I leave this out :-)

**define variables**

```
mv <- -999 #missing value to use
var_temp <- ncvar_def("temperatura", "celsius", 
                      list(lon1, lat2, time_d), 
                      longname="Temp. da superfície", mv) 
var_rh <- ncvar_def("humidade", "%", 
                     list(lon1, lat2, time_d), 
                     longname = "humidade relativa", mv )
```

**add data**

Create an nc file: `ncnew <- nc_create(f, list(var_temp, var_rh))`

When adding values the object holding the data is molten to a 1d-array and a sequential write is started at the position specified by start. The dimension to write along is controlled by the values in count. If you have data like this:

```
long, lat, time, t
   1,   1,    1, 1
   2,   1,    1, 2
   1,   2,    1, 3
   2,   2,    1, 4
```

The command `ncvar_put(ncnew, var_temp,data$t,count=c(2,2,1))` would give you what you (probably) expect.

For you're data the first step is to create the indexes for the dimensions:

```
data$idx_lon <- match(data$long,xvals)
data$idx_lat <- match(data$lat,yvals)
data$idx_time <- match(data$time,unique(time))
```

Then create an array with the dimensions appropriate for your data:

```
m <- array(mv,dim = c(length(yvals),length(xvals),length(unique(time))))
```

Then fill the array with you're values:

```
for(i in 1:NROW(data)){
  m[data$idx_lat[i],data$idx_lon[i],data$idx_time[i]] <- data$temp[i]
}
```

if speed is a concern you could calculate the linear index vectorised and use this for value assignment.

Write the data

```
ncvar_put(ncnew, var_temp,m)
```

Note that you don't need `start` and `count`.

Finally close the nc file to write data to the disk `nc_close(ncnew)`
Optionally I would recommend you the `ncdump` console command to check your file.

**Edit**

Regarding your question whether to write a complete array or use `start` and `count` I believe both methods work reliable. Which one to prefer depends on your data and you're personal preferences.

I think the method of building an array, add the values and then write it as whole is easier to understand. However, when asking what is more efficient it depends on the data. If you're data is big and has many NA values I believe using multiple writes with start and count could be faster. If NA's are rare creating one matrix and do single write would be faster. If you're data is so big creating an extra array would exceed you're available memory you have to combine both methods.

Comment: Bueffish, first of all, thank you very much to spend some of your time to help me. Second, I much appreciate your clear answer and example code. It helped me a lot. I was dancing around this idea and had the same notion, but wasn't very clear on the solution. My main concern was the possibility of giving the wrong value to a given dimension. Using the `start` and `count` attributes is trustworthy? Or using the indexation, as you showed, would be more suitable? Both approaches worked perfectly. I will look more into the unlimited dimension, as I believe will be needed. Thank you mate. Regards

Comment: Hi, thanks for you're kind words. I edited my answer and tried to explain a bit when to use what method. Also note that in `?ncvar_put` is an example for writing 3d data along a unlimited dimension.

Comment: HI, thanks again @Bluefish. Once again your answer helped clear some thoughts. Everything I read about the subject is clearer now. Thanks again mate. Best regards.